# Removing index.php

Tags: yii, url-rewriting

I saw the tutorial Yii and some tutorials here, but none solved my problem. When I try to access any part of my web application without the index.php, it shows this:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Code's main.php:

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Code's .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `mod_rewrite` is installed and enabled in your Apache configuration.

Also, look at the logs for Apache as they may give you more information.

My htaccess personally does not include the first 2 lines you wrote (followsymlinks and indexignore ...).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [NE]
```

I've had "internal server errors" like yours when I made mistakes in my htaccess.